# How to uninstall ubuntu so that I've got an empty hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, windows, bios

I currently have ubuntu running on an old hard drive, I've since decided that I want to use this hard drive as a secondary to store games on. However, I don't know a method of uninstalling ubuntu that doesn't require replacing it with windows.

Comment: Power off your Ubuntu Computer and unplug the old hard drive. Plug it on the new system and format it.

Answer (score 0):

Install linux (say ubuntu, linux mint etc that you like) on a pen drive, plug it into your pc, then turn on the pc. Boot into the linux on your pen drive (the steps vary from pc to pc, so google the steps for your pc). Once in, open gparted (or install it if it is not preinstalled and then open it), choose the ubuntu partition, mark it for deletion, and create a new partition (most probably `ntfs` partition for windows, please check it), and hit ok. That should give you the empty hard drive and do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the same Ubuntu live USB/DVD that you used to install Ubuntu. From the boot menu select *Try Ubuntu without installing*. Open the Disks application from the Dash, and make a note of the device name of the disk on which Ubuntu is installed. The device name  has a form similar to `/dev/sdX` where `X` is a lower case letter. Open the GParted partition editor by clicking its icon in the Dash, and reformat the entire disk on which Ubuntu is installed. If you are planning to use this disk to store Windows games, I recommend formatting it as NTFS.